# Unable to parse Open API, or Google Service Configuration specification from openapiapp.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, asp.net-web-api, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi

I try to follow exactly [this tutorial] (https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/exposing-aspnet-webapi-using-dotnetcore-with-cloud-endpoints ), but I get the following error at trying `gcloud endpoints services deploy openapi.yaml` :

**ERROR: (gcloud.endpoints.services.deploy) Unable to parse Open API, or Google Service Configuration specification from [SampleSolution]**

The body of openapi.yaml :

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Notes API
  version: v1
host: [google cloud project ID].appspot.com
paths:
  /WeatherForecast:
    get:
      tags:
        - WeatherForecast
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
          content:
            text/plain:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/WeatherForecast'
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/WeatherForecast'
            text/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/WeatherForecast'
components:
  schemas:
    WeatherForecast:
      type: object
      properties:
        date:
          type: string
          format: date-time
        temperatureC:
          type: integer
          format: int32
        temperatureF:
          type: integer
          format: int32
          readOnly: true
        summary:
          type: string
          nullable: true
      additionalProperties: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I only see two things there:

1. `openapi: 3.0.1`. This should be `swagger: "2.0"` accordint ot the [Basic structure of an OpenAPI document](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-overview#basic_structure_of_an_openapi_document)
2. `host: [google cloud project ID].appspot.com`. This should contain the proper project Id.

**UPDATE**

After checking the composition of your file and the Endpoints openAPI Docs:

[OpenAPI feature limitations](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-limitations):

1. Currently, Cloud Endpoints accepts only version 2 of the OpenAPI Specification.
2. [The Components Section](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/components/) in the Swagger docs mentions that applies to openAPI3. This is not compatible with point 1.
3. I suggest to remake your file following [The basic structure of an OpenAPI document](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-overview#basic_structure_of_an_openapi_document)

Comment: host contains proper project id. I will try your solution and will give updates.

Comment: ERROR: (gcloud.endpoints.services.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot convert to service config.
'location: "unknown location"
kind: ERROR
message: "Invalid OpenAPI file. Please fix the schema errors:\nerror: object instance has properties which are not allowed by the schema: [\"components\"]\n    level: \"error\"\n    schema: {\"loadingURI\":\"http://swagger.io/v2/schema.json#\",\"pointer\":\"\"}\n    instance: {\"pointer\":\"\"}\n    domain: \"validation\"\n    keyword: \"additionalProperties\"\n    unwanted: [\"components\"]"
'

Comment: I tried with swagger and I got this. Also I tried to delete components and schemas keys.

Comment: im trying to deploy the same code, i will update here when i have any insight

Comment: hope you are able to make it work now. I had the same issue then I changed the format of the yaml to meet swagger 2.0 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Swashbuckle.AspNetCore now supports OpenApi 3, but it also has backwards compatibility with Swagger v2, by setting it up in Configure method (Startup class) with:

```
app.UseSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.SerializeAsV2 = true;
                });
```